# How can I install an older version of maas?

Tags: software-installation, maas

As of now, the [PPA](http://ppa.launchpad.net/maas/stable/ubuntu) consists of latest version of maas.

[image: Available Packages]

Is it possible to install an older version like maas-rack-controller/bionic 2.5.2?

We have installed maas HA in version 2.5.2 and we will add a new maas-rack-controller in 2.5.2.